# How do I make modprobe changes permanent?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have been having several issues with my touchpad since upgrading to 12.04LTS.  I believe it is an issue with the Elantech driver.  I have found that the following commands fix my problem, however, the changes seem to be reverted when I reboot.

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Is there a way I can make these changes permanent?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using a generic synaptic touchpad, but it fails to respond to tapping or scrolling actions under a new installation, you can run the following two commands to immediately make it work:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

To make this change permanent, create a file such as `touchpad.conf` under `/etc/modprobe.d/`, and put the following line in it:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

Answer (score 3):

Login as a super user (root) and open `/etc/rc.local` using nano or some other editor as shown below.

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add the lines to the file

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and Exit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and restart your system. It is done!

Comment: Still works for 16.04, creating /etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf didn't work.

Comment: I have to run modprobe pcspkr to make the buzzer work but putting that in /etc/rc.local did not work on Mint 21 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

Save your listed commands as a shell script (*.sh) and set that script to run before LightDM by doing the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add this line to the bottom of lightdm.conf

```
display-setup-script=/home/[your username]/Scripts/synScript.sh
```

Or whatever your script is called and wherever it is located.

P.S. Don't forget to make your script executable!

---

.pc

Answer (score 0):

I used crontab to schedule these commands at reboot.
To do this I opened file **crontab** as superuser in folder **etc**:

```
sudo gedit /etc/crontab
```

Then I inserted a line at the end, so that the commands are executed as root at reboot (applied to every user):

```
@reboot root modprobe -e psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: i think the command should be ```@reboot root modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```