# Touchpad not detected in any linux distribution

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, input

I've installed several linux distributions and my touchpad isn't working in any of them. USB Mouse works fine and the touchpad works on Windows 10. I tried many different things I've found and none of them got good results. I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad 320 laptop running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 dual boot.

My xinput output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer     (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Edit: 
Output from `pt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`:

```
Xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1
Version table:
   1.9.0-1ubuntu1 500
     500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
```

And `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-libinput`:

```
Xserver-xorg-input-libinput:
   Installed: 0.25.0-0ubuntu1
   Candidate: 0.25.0-0ubuntu1
   Version table:
   *** 0.25.0-0ubuntu1 500
           500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Most likely the touchpad is not supported by Linux yet. You can try a newer kernel to check if the support has been added.

Comment: Does the computer see the touchpad? `lshw` will tell you, and `journalctl -b` will list all system messages since boot, including, maybe, a reason why no touchpad.

Comment: `lshw` doesn't show any touchpad and I can't see any touchpad related line on `journalctl -b` :/

Comment: Installed the newest kernel, still not working. Is there any way I can report it to Ubuntu?

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-libinput`.

Comment: ps: also see https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/6nnpcp/touchpad_not_working_on_lenovo_ideapad_320/

Comment: User space xserver-xorg drivers are not related. It is a kernel issue.

Comment: You can report it to Canonical by running `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: Reported to Canonical. Hope they fix it quick :/

Comment: Please try again, this time with the developing version, which comes with the newest linux kernel and hardware drivers (tested with Ubuntu), [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate/1018060#1018060)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the following?

```sh
sudo modprobe -r psmouse  # PS/2 mouse driver
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps  # Add proto=imps option
```

Comment: Yup, didn't work either

Comment: Related: [mouse - How do I make modprobe changes permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/a/127761/349837)