# Asus Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, asus

My touchpad is no longer working.  Here is what I get when I do not have an external mouse plugged in:

```
$ sudo xinput list
[sudo] password for gwlester: 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Help!!!

Comment: Asus model? Should have something like `FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech Touchpad`. Try with a live distro and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/943339/349837)/[this](https://askubuntu.com/a/127761/349837)

Comment: The model is a GL753V

Comment: As suggested, did:
sudo modprobe -r psmouse  # PS/2 mouse driver
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps  # Add proto=imps option


No errors but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Some diagnostics would be helpful.

1. Does the touchpad work when running from a [Live Ubuntu USB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/)? If so, you know the cause is with the installed system; if not, the cause is hardware.
2. What occurred *before* this issue? Ubuntu update? Power failure? Spilled coffee? Something else?
3. Have you shut down and rebooted?
4. In the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://geek-university.com/synaptic/), have you checked status of packages? Tried *Edit | Fix Broken Packages*?
5. Have you tried [fixing broken packages](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages) from Terminal?

Comment: 1) Downloading Live and will attempt to run and report results.
2) Stopped working after an upgrade.  Finally got annoyed enough to fix.
3) Many, many, many times.
4) Yes, shows no broken packages.
5) Yes, shows nothing wrong.

Comment: You state, "Stopped working after an upgrade." That important bit of data should have been in the question, which would have led to an obvious suggestion: back out the upgraded packages. Of course, by now, there will have been *other* upgrades, making it more difficult to identify the culprit(s).